# TimThumb src parameter is a url with it's own parameters

Tags: php, timthumb

I'm implementing timthumb to resize and create thumbnails of attached images on a forum.

The forum uploads the images and they're accessible via it's own query string, and it also creates 1 thumbnail (for the post/thread view).

The tim thumb is needed to create another, even smaller thumbnail for display on the homepage, where only a tiny version is needed. So I need to specify the attachment url, which delivers a jpeg image, jpeg headers, etc, to timthumb.

The problem is as follows.

http://example.com/timthumb.php?src=/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=276.0;attach=1357;image&w=120

The attachment url works and delivers the image, but as it's part of another query string, I don't know how to separate it. I've used ampersands to separate the timthumb parameters, and semicolons to separate the forum attachment parameters for clarity in the question.

Thanks, regards, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

if You using php use urlencode for a source url:

```
timthumb?src = "<? urlencode("http://link_to_your_file.jpg"); ?>"
```